# .Net - Merging In-memory Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, merge, .net-assembly

I have a project where I am dynamically compiling code from a string as such:

```
 public static Assembly BuildItem(Document doc)
 {
     CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
     parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
     parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;


     CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
     CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, doc.GetCompileString());


     return results.CompiledAssembly;
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is take these resulting assembly files and combine them into a single assembly without writing them to disk.  I know about ILMerge, and that is currently a fallback plan if I need to do that.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling you can pass an array of source files, then they're all in one assembly. e.g

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, new string [] { source1, source2... })
```

Alternatively if you really have to call CompileAssemblyFromSource seperately for each source. You could add all the generated assemblies as embedded resources to another assembly using

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
foreach(string assemblyPath in generatedAssemblies)
    provider.EmbeddedResources.Add(assemblyPath);
```

Then...

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
```

...where source is from the following blog which describes how to load assemblies from embedded resources...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx